# Creating Foreign Key in Laravel Migrations

Tags: php, laravel

please help for solution this problem 
//error massage

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `llc05`.`posts`(errno:150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delet e cascade on update cascade)

```
//laravel code 
public function up() { 
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) { 
        $table->bigIncrements('id'); 
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); 
        $table->unsignedInteger('catagory_id'); 
        $table->string('title',128); 
        $table->longtext('content'); 
        $table->string('thumbnail_path',128); 
        $table->string('status',32)->default('draft'); 
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade'); 
        $table->foreign('catagory_id')->references('id')->on('catagories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade'); $table->timestamps(); 
    }); 
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your migration to this:-

```
public function up() { 
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) { 
        $table->bigIncrements('id'); 
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); 
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('catagory_id'); 
        $table->string('title',128); 
        $table->longtext('content'); 
        $table->string('thumbnail_path',128); 
        $table->string('status',32)->default('draft'); 
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade'); 
        $table->foreign('catagory_id')->references('id')->on('catagories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade'); $table->timestamps(); 
    }); 
}
```

Because you are referencing to the `bigIncrements` so, you need `unsignedBigInteger`

I hope it'll resolve your problem

Comment: Yap, this code work..........many many thanks Mr. Khalid Khan for given solution.

Comment: @pksaidur can you mark my answer correct . :)